# Python: replace all instances of alphanumeric substring, excluding higher order numbers

Tags: python, regex, replace

Using re.sub, I'm trying to find and replace all instances of an alphanumeric substring (e.g., run1) except instances of the substring where the numeric is a higher order number (e.g., run12).

I thought a lookbehind `(?<![0-9])` would prevent "run12" from matching, but I'm not familiar with its usage and probably using it incorrectly.

```py
import re

mystring = '/mypath/run1/run12_run1_file.txt'
mynewstring = re.sub(r'run1(?<![0-9])',r'run2',mystring)
print mynewstring
```

Ideally, this would return:

```py
/mypath/run2/run12_run2_file.txt
```

Instead, it's matching nothing and returning:

```py
/mypath/run1/run12_run1_file.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how about `run1_`

Comment: This would not replace ```run1/```, but blhsing's answer helped... I should be using a lookahead rather than a lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

You should use negative lookahead instead of negative lookbehind since you're trying to avoid matching `run1` that's followed by a digit:

```
mynewstring = re.sub(r'run1(?!\d)', 'run2', mystring)
```